# An easier way to build queries in Play Framework 1.x / JPA using "in"?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

Is there a shortcut in Play Framework / JPA to save building this query manually?

```
public List<User> getAllExceptThese(Collection<String> emails) {
    checkArgument(!emails.isEmpty());

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("email not in (");
    boolean first = true;
    for (String email : emails) {
        if (!first) {
            query.append(", ");
        }
        first = false;
        query.append("?");
    }
    query.append(")");

    return findAll(query.toString(), emails.toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Play-framework, but if it's possible to create JPQL-queries, how about building a [Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html)-object and using it to insert the collection instead...

```
  public List<User> getAllExceptThese(Collection<String> emails) {
            checkArgument(!emails.isEmpty());

            String queryStr = "FROM User u WHERE u.email NOT IN (:excludedEmails)";

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr);
            query.setParameter("excludedEmails", emails);
            return (List<User>)query.getResultList();
  }
```

Comment: Does it support passing collections as query parameters?

Comment: @ripper234: Yes it does. I've used Hibernate as a JPA-provider and never had problems with using collections in named parameters (as long as the operator can take a list of parameters, like IN). As an added bonus, setParameter will protect you from SQL-injection via malicious values inside the collection.

Comment: My method of building the query still protects from SQL injections ... I am using named parameters.

Comment: @ripper234: Right, sorry, didn't notice the "?"'s at first... anyway, glad you got it working this way.